# How to make 3D wall gallery in Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, flex3

I like to create a [Flex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Flex) application, an image gallery, which comes like 3D wall. How can I do that? Is there any examples available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of good examples of 3d image wall's in AS3 if you do a quick google.

A lot of them will be using the PaperVision 3d library.

Here is an example of using PV3d in flex:

http://www.unitzeroone.com/blog/2006/12/12/papervision-3dflex-2-example-flex-makes-its-first-pv3d-steps/

Comment: Thank you for the answer after this long time. Papervision 3d doesnt have direct methods to create 3dwall and the one they provided was paid one. But I managed to create a 3dwall by reading some blogs telling the ideas and some code snippets from blogs. Once I complete it with perfection, I will post demo source.

Answer (score 1):

The question sounds like you're trying to learn the Flex technology.

So the first thing I'd do is to get [Tour de Flex](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/tourdeflex/).

Use case examples and source code.